# How to create a RESTful URI that map an action

Tags: api, rest

I have a REST api on documents.

```
GET|POST|PUT|DELETE /documents/{id}
```

I should implement a "distribute" action that apply to all documents resources.

This one hurt me because "distribute" and "{id}" are on the same level:

```
POST /documents/distribute
```

I wonder what is the REST best practice to implements action URI?

Thanks!

Comment: One solution may to add a prefix to the id `GET|POST|PUT|DELETE /documents/doc-{id}`

Comment: `POST /distribute/documents` or `POST /documents?action=distribute`? What will the "distribute" action exactly do?

Comment: distribute create documents and distribute their by email

Comment: `POST /documents/_distribute` is maybe a good compromise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate resource for distributed documents:

```
POST /distributed-documents/
-> {"document-id": 12345}
```

Comment: I agree. Actions can be seen as resources even if `distributed-documents` does not exist outside the request